# A better way to check for database updates in parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a parse database which is updated 4-5 times a day. 
The data from the database is fetched and shown in an android app. However, the app has to fetch data everytime on start as it cant check whether the database has been updated or not yet. Is there any way I can check for database updates and load the changes the next time the app is launched?
I currently tried saving the most recent objectID in a file and checking it with the top entry of database everytime the app starts but that doesnt work(data is sorted in descending order).

Comment: you can create another table with column "last_db_updated_at", and update this single row/tuple every time you make a update/insert in your db data. Fetch this column first to know whether data is updated or not